# Вычисление схожести массивов в PostgreSQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Мне необходимо создать функцию для вычисления схожести массивов на стороне postgres. Функция - некий аналог функции numpy.linalg.norm().
Во входные параметрах два массива double precision, в каждом из них по 128 элементов. На выходе один double precision.

На python это делается так:

```
def linalg(self, encoding1, encoding1):
   res = float(0)
   for i in range(0, 127):
      res += abs(en1[i] - en2[i])
   return res
```

Помогите написать SQL-запрос для реализации такой функции на стороне сервера.

Comment: Реализуйте на стороне сервера функцию, в точности как на питоне, с двумя массивами на входе https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-createfunction и той же логикой в середине https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/plpgsql-control-structures#plpgsql-control-structures-loops

Comment: Либо разворачивайте массивы unnset в набор строк, переклеивайте их, вычисляйте и собирайте обратно в массив array_agg

Answer (score 0):

Я смог написать функцию на plpgsql, но она возвращает None.
Вот весь код  моего проекта.

Создание таблиц и функций в бд:

```
from psycopg2 import connect

with connect(host='localhost',
             port=5432,
             database='uNeuro',
             user='postgres',
             password='3680') as conn, conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("SET TIMEZONE='Europe/Moscow'")

    cur.execute("SET DateStyle='SQL, DMY'")

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE profile_table( "
                "id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, "
                "firstname varchar(50) NOT NULL, "
                "lastname varchar(50) NOT NULL, "
                "patronymic varchar(50) NOT NULL, "
                "gender boolean NOT NULL, "
                "date_of_birth timestamp NOT NULL, "
                "registration_date timestamp NOT NULL);")

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE visit_table( "
                "id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, "
                "visit_time timestamp NOT NULL, "
                "profile_id int references profile_table(id) NOT NULL, "
                "point int NOT NULL);")
    
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE img_table( "
                "id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, "
                "profile_id int references profile_table(id) NOT NULL, "
                "img bytea, "
                "encoding double precision[]);")

    cur.execute("CREATE FUNCTION linalg(en1 double precision[], en2 double precision[]) RETURNS float8 AS $$"
                "DECLARE"
                "   s float8 := 0;"
                "BEGIN"
                "   FOR i IN 0..127 LOOP"
                "       s = s + abs(en1[i] - en2[i]);"
                "   END LOOP;"
                "   RETURN s;"
                "END;"
                "$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;")
```

Файл postgre.py

```
    import io
    import random
    import numpy as np
    
    class Interface:
        def __init__(self, cur):
            self.cur = cur
    
        def _img_to_byte_array(self, image):
            imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
            image.save(imgByteArr, format=image.format)
            imgByteArr = imgByteArr.getvalue()
            return imgByteArr
    
        def _cur_to_list(self):
            res = list()
            for row in self.cur:
                res.append(row)
            return res
    
        def _datetime_to_string(self, date):
            return str(date.year) + "-" + str(date.month) + "-" + str(date.day) + " "\
                   + str(date.hour) + ":" + str(date.minute) + ":" + str(date.second)
    
        def _make_random_encoding(self):
            arr = np.array(range(128), float)
            for i in range(128):
                arr[i] = random.random()
            return arr
    
        def _encoding_to_string(self, encoding):
            if (encoding.shape == (1, 128)):
                encoding = encoding[0]
            res = ' {'
            for a in encoding:
                res += str(a)
                res += ', '
            res = res[:res.rfind(',')] + ' } '
            return res
    
        def _test(self, en1, en2):
            self.cur.execute("SELECT linalg(%(en1)s, %(en2)s);",
                             {"en1": self._encoding_to_string(en1),
                              "en2": self._encoding_to_string(en2)})
            return self._cur_to_list()
    
        def set_profile(self, lastname, firstname, gender, date_of_birth, patronymic="None"):
            if (gender == "man"):
                gender = "true"
            else:
                gender = "false"
    
            self.cur.execute(
                "INSERT INTO profile_table (firstname, lastname, patronymic, gender, date_of_birth, registration_date)"
                "VALUES (%(firstname)s, %(lastname)s, %(patronymic)s, %(gender)s, %(date_of_birth)s, "
                "%(registration_date)s);",
                {"lastname": lastname,
                 "firstname": firstname,
                 "patronymic": patronymic,
                 "gender": gender,
                 "date_of_birth": self._datetime_to_string(date_of_birth),
                 "registration_date": "NOW()"
                 })
    
        def set_visit(self, profile_id, point):
            self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO visit_table (visit_time, profile_id, point) "
                             "VALUES (NOW(), %(profile_id)s, %(point)s);",
                             {"profile_id": profile_id,
                              "point": point})
    
        def set_img(self, profile_id, img, encoding):
            self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO img_table (profile_id, img, encoding) "
                             "VALUES (%(profile_id)s, %(img)s, %(encoding)s);",
                             {"profile_id": profile_id,
                              "img": self._img_to_byte_array(img),
                              "encoding": self._encoding_to_string(encoding)})
    
        def get_profiles(self):
            self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM profile_table;")
            return self._cur_to_list()
    
        def get_visits(self):
            self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM visit_table;")
            return self._cur_to_list()
```

Файл main.py

```
from postgre import Interface
from psycopg2 import connect

with connect(host='localhost',
             port=5432,
             database='uNeuro',
             user='postgres',
             password='3680') as conn, conn.cursor() as cur:
    I = Interface(cur)

    en1 = I._make_random_encoding()
    en2 = I._make_random_encoding()

    a = I._test(en1, en2)
    print(a)
```

При исполнении main.py в консоль выводится [(None,)], что неправильно.